# JSON to TypeScript in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an http service in angular which makes call to web api to get JSON data which needs to be deserialized to typescript (.ts) objects. The name of key in JSON (i.e. "Property") is not matching to what I have in typescript (i.e. "property") - meaning JSON data is Uppercase and typescript is lowercase. Is there a mapping function with http calls in angular where I can deserialize the json to typescript?

Example JSON coming back from web api

```
"Packages": [
      {
          "IsESignAllowed": false,
          "IsEnabled": true,
          "Name": "Brokerage Accounts Package",
          "PackageId": 2
      }
]
```

Associated `.ts` file on Angular

```
export class Package {
    public isESignAllowed: boolean;
    public isEnabled: boolean;
    public name: string;
    public packageId: number;
}
```

Comment: That mapping should happen on your back end, not in your Angular. You need to register your web api config to format json using camelcasing.

Comment: Also, your statement "`meaning JSON data is Uppercase and typescript is lowercase`" is incorrect. JSON casing standard is camel casing, as is typescript. They're both Javascript after all.

Answer (score 2):

You can add some serialisation functions to your Package class in typescript, this will allow you to map the JSON object from the server to a new Package object in TS.

As mentioned, it would be best to keep standard camel case convention everywhere - and have the server send JSON with lowercase property names, however, if this is not possible, this can still be handled in your serialisation functions.

```
export class Package {
    public isESignAllowed: boolean;
    public isEnabled: boolean;
    public name: string;
    public packageId: number;

    static fromJson(jsonObj: any) {
        const newPackage = new this();
        newPackage.isESignAllowed = jsonObj.IsESignAllowed;
        newPackage.isEnabled = jsonObj.IsEnabled;
        newPackage.name = jsonObj.Name;
        newPackage.packageId = jsonObj.PackageId;
        return newPackage;
    }

    public toJson(): any {
        const jsonObj: any = {};
        jsonObj.IsESignAllowed = this.isESignAllowed;
        jsonObj.IsEnabled = this.isEnabled;
        jsonObj.Name = this.name;
        jsonObj.PackageId = this.packageId;
        return jsonObj;
    }
}
```

Once you have received the JSON from the server, you can now map the array of packages over the new Package.fromJson() function, to create a list of Package objects.

```
const packages = serverResponse.Packages.map(packageJson => Package.fromJson(packageJson));
```